# Javascript object array grouping and summing

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping, aggregate-functions

I have been tasked with creating a time sheet table that will display the hours worked on by each client per day. The table should look something like the snippet below:

```css
table, td, th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="testTable" class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Client name</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>client1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>client2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is that after querying the timesheet items needed to populate the table, i am unsure how to group each item by the client name and day of the week. The array retrieved would look similar to this:

```js
timesheetItems = [
  timesheetItem = {
      clientName: client1,
      hoursWorked: 2,
      day: Monday
    },
  timesheetItem = {
      clientName: client1,
      hoursWorked: 3,
      day: Monday
    },
  timesheetItem = {
      clientName: client1,
      hoursWorked: 4,
      day: Wednesday
    },
  timesheetItem = {
      clientName: client2,
      hoursWorked: 4,
      day: Monday
    }
  
  ];
```

the grouped array should group all the timesheet items into one object per client and have keys for each day of the week that contains the sum of hours worked for that day. The final array should look something like this:

```js
groupedArray = {
  Client1 = {
    Mon: 5,
    tues: 3,
    ...
    sun: 0
  },
  client2 = {
    mon:2,
    ...
  },
  client3 = {
  ...
  },
  ...
}
```

So if anyone could suggest how to go about grouping the timesheet items array so that the outcome will look like the snippet above, so i can easily loop from the grouped array to populate the table, it would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate an array you can use `reduce` :

```
const groupedArray = timesheetItems.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (!prev[curr.clientName]) {
        prev[curr.clientName] = {};
    }
    if (!prev[curr.clientName][curr.day]) {
        prev[curr.clientName][curr.day] = 0
    }
    prev[curr.clientName][curr.day] += curr.hoursWorked;
    return prev; 
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and check for existent objects. If not exist assign a new oject or value.

```js
var timesheetItems = [{ clientName: 'client1', hoursWorked: 2, day: 'Monday' }, { clientName: 'client1', hoursWorked: 3, day: 'Monday' }, { clientName: 'client1', hoursWorked: 4, day: 'Wednesday' }, { clientName: 'client2', hoursWorked: 4, day: 'Monday' }],
    grouped = {};

timesheetItems.forEach(a => {
    grouped[a.clientName] = grouped[a.clientName] || {};
    grouped[a.clientName][a.day] = (grouped[a.clientName][a.day] || 0) + a.hoursWorked;
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We might utilize a `tableMaker()` function to generate a table from an array of objects where each object designate a table row, the properties of the objects designate the headers and the values are the data cells. But first we have to convert our data into a form that the `tableMaker()` function can understand. Such as

```
[ { 'Client Name': 'client1',
    Monday: 5,
    Tuesday: 0,
    Wednesday: 4,
    Thursday: 0,
    Friday: 0 },
  { 'Client Name': 'client2',
    Monday: 4,
    Tuesday: 0,
    Wednesday: 0,
    Thursday: 0,
    Friday: 0 } ]
```

So here is the code for the table.

```js
function tableMaker(o,h=true){
  var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
      rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
}

function giveMeNewClient(o){
  var templateObject = {
                     "Client Name": "",
                          "Monday": 0,
                         "Tuesday": 0,
                       "Wednesday": 0,
                        "Thursday": 0,
                          "Friday": 0
                       };
  return Object.assign(templateObject,o);
}
var timesheetItems = [{
                        clientName: "client1",
                       hoursWorked: 2,
                               day: "Monday"
                      },
                      {
                       clientName: "client1",
                       hoursWorked: 3,
                               day: "Monday"
                      },
                      {
                       clientName: "client1",
                       hoursWorked: 4,
                               day: "Wednesday"
                      },
                      {
                       clientName: "client2",
                       hoursWorked: 4,
                               day: "Monday"
                      }
                     ],

         tableData = timesheetItems.reduce((res,c) => { var client = res.find(o => o["Client Name"] === c.clientName);
                                                        client ? client[c.day]+= c.hoursWorked
                                                               : res.push(giveMeNewClient({"Client Name": c.clientName, [c.day]: c.hoursWorked}));
                                                        return res;
                                                      },[]),
         tableHTML = tableMaker(tableData);
myTable.innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```